# what does <dbl> in R stand for?

Tags: r

printing a tibble in R outputs the content in rows and columns.

```
> my_data <- as_tibble(iris)
> my_data
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
```

there are some abbreviations beneath column names, like , .

it seems that  stands for "factor".

what does  stand for?

Comment: `<dbl>' stands for double, which is short for [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). It's simply the format of storing a real number.

Comment: @Durden thank you so much! you are so cool